# Splitting strings using a delimiter in python

Tags: python

OK so I have a string that has this:

```
Dan|warrior|54
```

I'm trying to make so I can use python and split it using `|` as the delimiter. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
dan = 'dan|warrior|54'
print dan.split('|')
```

and that results into this:

```
['dan', 'warrior', '54']
```

I know it's incomplete but what do I have to do to finish it? Yes, I tried googling this problem... but it's not happening. :(

I want so that I can choose specifically which one from the delimiter so if I was `dan.split('|')[1]` .. it would pick `warrior`. See my point?

Comment: What excatly are you trying to do?  What is your desired result?

Comment: Tell us exactly, what do you want to do? 'Cause your question doesn't show anything working wrong...

Comment: Ignoring that your question is very lacking (for starters, define "incomplete"): Would a [CSV parser](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-examples) make this problem as a whole disappear? (Yes, the C is for "comma", but other delimiters including pipes are common and supported)

Comment: I reworded it better -- sorry.

Comment: _Why_ is this incomplete? What is your expected output? We are smart and all-around awesome people, but we are not psychics.

Comment: but if you do 'dan|warior|54'.split('|')[1], you actually will get 'warior'!

Comment: Nope, still don't see your point.

Comment: @jahkr: perhaps you should try rewording it _worse_...

Comment: Yes, you will get 'warior', but you have not said why that is not the proper output.

Comment: Have you even TRIED this? Your code does *exactly* what you say you want.

Comment: Actually no because I was guessing at the time and had to leave in a hurry so I couldn't test it. But thanks.

Comment: questions is so simple, and you all have so many strange questions , he want's exact functionality as stated here http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php split string to dictionary by delimiter.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

So, your input is 'dan|warrior|54' and you want "warrior". You do this like so:

```
>>> dan = 'dan|warrior|54'
>>> dan.split('|')[1]
"warrior"
```